# How to access windows file shares from a Mac?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, mac, file-sharing

I have a windows PC with file shares that I would like to access on my Mac. I have enabled file sharing on public and private networks on advanced sharing in control centre on the windows pc and when I go on my Mac and then go to: connect to a server > type smb://*windows pc IP address* > connect and enter in the username and password I just get the Access to your account on the server "windows IP address" has been denied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You tagged this Windows-10 so I assume that's the version of Windows you're running, but what version of macOS are you running? Also, how are these devices connected to the network? Are they on the same IP subnet? Can they ping each other?

Comment: You can also check windows 10's SMB server event log to see if there are something related. As Spiff said, make they can ping each other.

Answer (score 0):

First, to confirm, you open properties and then the sharing tab on Windows and shared the folders you want to access. You also set the permissions by choosing what accounts can access the share as read, change and full control?

Once you have shared the folders in question and set the permissions appropriately it is simply a matter of connecting to the Windows PC from the Mac.

I have found that it is just easier to connect to the PC from the Mac using the IP address of the PC. Yah hostnames *should* work fine, sometimes they just don't.

On the Mac (in Finder) Select the "Go" menu then "connect to server" and type in "SMB://" followed by the IP address of the PC followed by the share name. This is the name you gave the share on the PC. Like this:

```
SMB://192.168.1.15/share
```

The Mac will think for a few seconds and then ask you for a username and password. This is the part that is often done wrong. *You have to qualify the username by specifying where the username is from.*

If your PC is a member of an Active Directory domain the username needs to be prefixed with the domain name. If it is a stand-alone PC the username needs to be prefixed with the name of the computer. In both cases you get properties on the "My PC" icon, select properties and the name of the PC will be there.

Let's assume the name of my PC is "Fred" and the user that has access to my share is "Sally." In the username field on the Mac when you are asked to log in you would type in:

```
fred\sally
```

And then tab down to the password field and enter the password.

**NOTE** that it is important that you preface the user with the location of the user account (active directory or the PC itself) so the PC knows where to look for the account and then compare what the Mac sends it with what it thinks the password is. I have found it is good to actually have an account *with a password* rather than depending on setting permissions to "everyone" and logging on as Guest. Sometimes that fails for unknown reasons.

You can make your life easier by checking the box to save the password in the keychain before clicking on OK.

Assuming you have set up the PC for sharing properly, got the right IP address and the right share name. The Mac will open a new Finder window with the contents of the folder on your PC across the network.

There will also be an icon for that folder on your Mac's desktop. I would make an alias of it to make getting to it again easier. Macs don't "map a drive" like PCs but if you save the password in the keychain and make that alias, you just have to double-click the alias to open the shared folder on your Mac.